# Verification of Proof: Define the image and possibilities for ker$\phi$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume $\phi: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$ is defined by $\phi(n)=a^n$.

We know this is a homomorphism already.  Its image, clearly is the cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$.  What I don't get is the following explanation:

If $\langle a\rangle$ is an infinite cyclic group then the kernel is $0$.  If $\langle a\rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ then the kernel is $n\mathbb{Z}$.

How do you get this?  If possible please explain in detail.

Comment: Change $<a>$ with $<1>$ if $1$ has infinite order then $<1>=Z$ so the kernel is $0$. if $1$ has order $n$ then $<1>=Z_n$ so the kernel is $nZ$ as $Z/nZ\cong Z_n$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Assume the kernel is different from $0.$ Then, for some $n$ it is $\phi(n)=a^n=1.$ What is $\phi(n+1)=a^{n+1}?$ More generally, what is $\phi(n+k)=a^{n+k}$ for $k=1,\cdots, n?$ Can the cyclic subgroup generated by $a$ be infinite?